# Assembly reference not being added with custom nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I've got two nuget packages where one depends on the other. When installing the second one, an assembly reference for the assembly in the first package gets correctly added to the project references, however I'm somehow unable to add the latter one. Is there something wrong with my spec?

```
// first
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>first</id>
        ...
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="..\src\MyFirstProject\bin\v4.0\MyFirstProject.dll" target="lib\net40-client\MyFirstProject.dll" />
        <file src="..\src\MyFirstProject\bin\v4.0\MyFirstProject.xml" target="lib\net40-client\MyFirstProject.xml" />
        <file src="..\src\MyFirstProject\bin\v4.5\MyFirstProject.dll" target="lib\net45\MyFirstProject.dll" />
        <file src="..\src\MyFirstProject\bin\v4.5\MyFirstProject.xml" target="lib\net45\MyFirstProject.xml" />
        <file src="..\src\MyFirstProject\bin\v4.6\MyFirstProject.dll" target="lib\net46\MyFirstProject.dll" />
        <file src="..\src\MyFirstProject\bin\v4.6\MyFirstProject.xml" target="lib\net46\MyFirstProject.xml" />
    </files>
</package>

// second
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>second</id>
        ...
        <dependencies>
            <dependency id="first" ...
        </dependencies
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="..\src\MySecondProject\bin\v4.6\MySecondProject.dll" target="lib\net46\MySecondProject.dll" />
        <file src="..\src\MySecondProject\bin\v4.6\MySecondProject.xml" target="lib\net46\MySecondProject.xml" />
    </files>
</package>
```

The second project is only available for .NET4.6 since I'm using some framework specific features shipped with this release. The target project I'm trying to install the package to is also a .NET4.6 project.

Validated:

- Target project is .NET4.6
- Package can be correctly created
- Assemblies reside in the `lib\` folder
- Assemblies are correctly being packed
- Nuget package gets correctly installed
- Entry in `packages.config` with the right framework version is made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed it.

The problem was the content of the `packages.config`. I initially created the target project as a .NET4.5 project and downloaded the .NET4.6 nuget package which caused the assembly reference to not being added. After I noticed my mistake, I switched over to .NET4.6 as the projects platform and adjusted the package version in the `packages.config` manually, but somehow VS memorized that setting so it didn't change anything. Only after I completely removed every package from the `package.config` and installed them again, it magically started to work. Weird. :)